# Can a monk use a quarterstaff for the attacks from Flurry of Blows?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, monk, unarmed-combat

I have a Level 3 Air Genasi Monk with a quarterstaff. When I take Flurry of Blows, do I have to attack without a weapon, are there certain weapons I can use, or can I use any monk weapon as my Flurry of Blows attack? How does this work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Attacks made with Flurry of Blows must be unarmed strikes.

The description of [Flurry of Blows](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#Ki-228) says (emphasis mine):

> Immediately after you take the Attack action on your turn, you can spend 1 ki point to make two *unarmed strikes* as a bonus action.

So the attacks attendant to the Flurry of Blows bonus action must be unarmed strikes.

Comment: Therefore you should attack with the quarterstaff and then use it as a pole to lift yourself briefly into the air as you deliver two kicks to your foe before landing back on your feet where you were.

Comment: Descriptively I've always allowed the quarterstaff to be used for the extra attacks, but mechanically they're 100% unarmed strikes.

Comment: It would require waiting for a couple of levels, but once you get to Monk 5, quarterstaff attacks and unarmed attacks do the same amount of damage (via the increase in your Martial Arts die), and at Monk 6 your unarmed attacks count as magical (Ki-Empowered Strikes). Unless you need to be using specifically a quarterstaff (or another Monk weapon), unarmed strikes are arguably better to use anyway - you can't disarmed without, well, being dis-*armed* (and -legged and -headed, and then you have bigger problems). Flavour them as you will, if your DM allows, of course.

Comment: Provided the monk can two hand the quarterstaff, it'll out damage unarmed strikes all the way up to Monk 11.